# Copying tables from schema or database

Tags: sql, oracle

I use oracle as my database.

I am confused with the concept between schema and database. I looked around here and couldn't find any explicit defined example.

Suppose we have a QA, DEV and production environment and suppose I have three QA environments. Between the three QA environment, will they generally have different database or different schema?

Suppose those three different QA environments have different data in each environment. And suppose I want to create a new fourth QA environment and want to copy a table (lets call this table `foo`) from one of the already existing QA environment (lets call this environment `QA_1`) to the new QA environment (lets call this `QA_NEW`). Will I be copying the `schema` table `foo` from `QA_1` to `QA_NEW` or will I be copying the `database` table from `QA_1` to `QA_NEW`?

Comment: `database.schema.table@DBLINK` if you have links setup between different environments (assuming different servers)  So if I wanted to copy from Dev to Q I could (assuming I was logged into Q) `Create table foo as (Select * from Database.Schema.Foo@Dev)`  generally you don't need to specify the database however so `Create table foo as (Select * from Schema.Foo@Dev)`  would create table foo in Q from the structure and data in dev.

Answer (score 0):

databases are physical (data files, blocks. etc.).
schemas are usernames (owners) of logical storage objects (tables, mviews, etc.) within the database

In your case, you have 3 QA databases (QA_1, QA_2 .. QA_N), each with their own schemas - likely of the same schema names (usernames). You'd be copying the database.schema.table to another database.schema.table

QA_1.myschema.foo -> QA_2.myschema.foo

You'd say "Foo table lives in the QA_1 database and is owned by the 'myschema' schema."

Answer (score 0):

You will want to copy the entire database to the new environment so that all environments match.

A schema is similar to a namespace. A database can have multiple namespaces and you'll likely want to copy all.